# "Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active" error in loop

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm sorry for asking this question. I've read alot just like it, but never found a solution that I successfully could implement. All the tips and tricks that I've found has been  to no use for me.

I have a large associative array with data that I want to insert into a mysql database using a stored procedure with PDO.

```
$data_arr = {a lot of data with keys: Name, Nbr, Val} //This is really 41 columns
$inputs = array('Name','Nbr','Val');
$query = 'CALL add_edit_standard(:Name,:Nbr,:Val)';
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
foreach($inputs AS $Akey => $Aval){
    $values[$Aval]=0;
    $stmt->bindParam(':'.$Aval,$values[$Aval]);
}
foreach($data_arr AS $key => $val){
    $values = $val;
    $stmt->execute();
    $res = $stmt->fetchAll();
}
```

This works perfectly fine for the first row in $data_arr, but the second and the rest throws an error:

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll(). Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.

I've tried with the fetchAll(), as well as the connection attribute with no luck.
I've also tried to make a new statement for each call:

```
foreach($data_arr AS $key => $val)
{
    $values = $val;
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    foreach($inputs AS $Akey => $Aval)
    {
        $stmt->bindValue(':'.$Aval,$values[$Aval]);
    }
    $stmt->execute();
    $res = $stmt->fetchAll();
    $stmt->closeCursor();
}
```

Again, this works perfectly for the first row, but then throws the following error:

> Warning: Packets out of order. Expected 1 received 57. Packet size=7

I have tried everything I've come up with. Please help me to find a way to make it work.

Comment: I see that someone gave me a downvote. It would be nice to know why. What information is lacking in my question? Is there an answer to it somewhere else that I have missed?

Comment: Why are you trying to build dynamic queries using named parameters?

Comment: Because there are so many parameters, 41 of them. It would be a hack to create 41 named variables, one for each parameter and then set all in the loop. Do you think that is creating the problem? Its working for the first row of the data array, so it seems like it is something else to me.

Comment: That is why you should be using unnamed parameters `?`

Comment: I still need to order them correctly according to the input order of the stored procedure. But I will try that. Thanks. I still don't understand why this would help though.

Comment: Ok, now I understand the benefit from using unnamed placeholders :) Thanks for that! I saved code since I didn't need to bind any Values or parameters. That was nice. But the errors are still there. Seems like mysql isn't ready for the next call? Should I set a timer?

Comment: I have added an Answer showing unnamed parameters and lazy binding. I would suggest you ask a new question with your modified code

Answer (score 1):

After you fetch all the results in your execute loop, you should get the next rowset and then close the cursor before attempting to execute the stored procedure again.  Try this:

```
foreach($data_arr AS $key => $val){
    $values = $val;
    $stmt->execute();
    $res = $stmt->fetchAll();
    $stmt->nextRowset();   // NEW: Get the next rowset after fetching your results
    $stmt->closeCursor();  // NEW: Close the cursor
}
```

The really important addition here is the call to [nextRowSet()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.nextrowset.php).  Under the hood, PDO is returning a second *rowset* which you need to access before executing a second (and subsequent) stored procedure on the same connection.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I will check this out. I actually don't remember how I solved this. I probably did some kind of workaround. I will try your solution next time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using unnamed parameters for dynamic queries are simpler than using named ones.

ie INSERT

```
$columnNames = array("id","name","address"); 
$columnStr ='';
foreach ($columnNames as $value)
    {
    $columnStr .= $value.",";
    }
$columnStr = substr($columnStr, 0, -1);
$values = array(1,"john","Home"); 
$params  = str_repeat('?, ', count($values) - 1) . '?';
$sql = "INSERT INTO table1 ($columnStr)  VALUES ($params) ";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql); 
$stmt->execute($values);
```

Produces query

```
INSERT INTO table1 (id,name,address) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

Comment: Thank you for streamlining my code. I really appreciate the feedback. It is a lot better compared to using named parameters. My question however is still unanswered. Both of my original approaches work for single calls, even though they might not be the most efficient. The problem lies in that the calls are made in a loop, and that something is causing the second, and so on, call to fail.