# PDO insert statement not working

Tags: php, pdo

My insert statement isnt working, im learning PDO and im pretty sure this is something to do with how im handling the quotes and double quotes but ive tried tons of scenarios and none of it work. My main issue is i cannot just print the string like i could with plain old mysql if the insert broke, im not sure what the best way to troubleshoot insert problems with PDO as this is a function i havent used in a long time

Let me first show my code:

```
$insert_array = array(
    "item_date"         =>  "$todays_date",
    "item_name"         =>  "$username",
    "item_user"         =>  "$item_desc",
    "item_description"  =>  "$item_game_type",
    "item_rating"       =>  "0",
    "total_ratings"     =>  "0"
);

$insert_db = $database->insert_sql("item_table",$insert_array);

    // loop through and bind the values in preperation for inserting
foreach ($insert_array as $field => $item) {
        $database->bind(':'.$field,$item);
}   

//execute the insert
$database->execute();
```

Here are the functions:

```
// compile list of escaped fieldnames
// will return `user_name`, `user_password_hash`, `user_email`, `user_activation_hash`
function dbFieldList($fields) {
$set = '';
foreach ($fields as $field => $item) {
    $set .= "`".$field."`,";
    }   
    return rtrim($set, ',');
}

// compile list of values
// will return :user_name, :user_password_hash, :user_email, :user_activation_hash
function dbValuePList($fields) {
    $set = '';
foreach ($fields as $field => $item) {
    $set .= ":".$field.",";
}   
return rtrim($set, ',');
}


// take data from arrays, clean the values in the
// dbFieldList and dbValuePList functions
// and create the insert query
// example INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`,`user_name`,`address`) VALUES (:user_id, :user_name)

public function insert_sql($table="item_table",$insert_array="",$debug=false){
    $this->query("
        INSERT INTO `".$table."`
        (". $this->dbFieldList($insert_array) .")
        VALUES (". $this->dbValuePList($insert_array) .")
        ");
    }
}

// prepare the query
public function query($query){
$this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
}
```

Now i also have some error code

```
if(!$insert_db){
echo "result of prepared insert statement: " . print_r($database->stmt) . "<br /><br />The result of the insert array values to be passed: " . print_r($insert_array) . "<br /><br />";
}
```

and the output is:

```
PDOStatement Object
(
    [queryString] => 
            INSERT INTO `item_table`
            (`item_date`,`item_name`,`item_user`,`item_description`,`item_rating`,`total_ratings`)
            VALUES (:item_date,:item_name,:item_user,:item_description,:item_rating,:total_ratings)

)

Array
(
    [item_date] => 2013-12-17 03:19:32
    [item_name] => testing
    [item_user] => test user
    [item_description] => All
    [item_rating] => 0
    [total_ratings] => 0
)
```

So my dilema is i know that the insert fails but i dont know how to check whats wrong, with my old mysql code i could use mysql_error(); but as you can see the output looks reasonably ok but its not the exact string so the only thing i can assume is wrong is the containers around the array. Instead of "$username" maybe it should be "'.$username.'" or something like that but ive tried a bunch of variations and failed, surely there is a way with PDO to get a meaningful error message or is purposely made to be this difficult.

Comment: Check the [PDO docs on error handling](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php). By default it errors silently, but you can and should configure it to throw exceptions via `setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)`

Comment: The query appears to be syntactically valid, by the way.

Comment: What's in the `bind` and `query` methods?

Comment: If you are extending `PDO`, then the `query()` call is inappropriate with what otherwise looks like a prepared statement. That should be an `execute()` with bound parameters.

Comment: See my [**Answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20607876/cannot-execute-queries-while-other-unbuffered-queries-are-active-error-in-loop/20612360#20612360) using unnamed parameters instead of named ones

Comment: I updated my code with the function query which is probably a bit misleading in its name, hopefully that clears up whats happening there, maybe im still doing it wrong though, not sure

Comment: I don't know if it's just a transcription error, but insert_sql doesn't return anything...

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not bind and execute the values to the right object. There:

```
foreach ($insert_array as $field => $item) {
        $database->bind(':'.$field,$item);
}   

//execute the insert
$database->execute();
```

it's actually `$insert_db` which contains the PDOStatement. try this:

```
foreach ($insert_array as $field => $item) {
        $insert_db->bind(':'.$field,$item);
}   

//execute the insert
$insert_db->execute();
```

otherwise, your code should not even need to put `$insert_db =`in front of `$database->insert_sql("item_table",$insert_array);`

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using

```
mysql_error();
```

You may use a try catch to find the error.

For instance:

```
try
{
    $q=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO table (`user`,`pass`) VALUES (:user,:pass)");
    $q->execute(array(":user" => $user, ":pass" => $pass));
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
    var_dump($q->debugDumpParams());
}
```

This is how I catch the errors.